# css-grid needs one fix in the layout for a footer in desktop view

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm pretty new to web development and I ran into an issue trying to set up a grid container for the footer on a page I'm trying to replicate. The first column of the grid should contain the logo image and the first paragraph but it's just placing the image. The second column should only contain the contact information but it currently displays the paragraph and the contact information together. I've been trying to figure out how to correct it but no luck yet. I included a picture of my results.

The html:

```html
    <footer>
      <div class="footer-content-container">
        <img src="./images/logo.svg" class="footer-logo col1">
        <div class="top-footer-content">
          <div class="footer-set col1">
            <img src="./images/icon-location.svg" class="footer-icon">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
              Beatae doloremque voluptate perspiciatis cum eaque ad, repellendus 
              totam ducimus.
            </p>
          </div>
          
          <div class="footer-set col2">
            <img src="./images/icon-phone.svg" class="footer-icon">
            <p>+1-543-123-4567</p>
          </div>

          <div class="footer-set col2">
            <img src="./images/icon-email.svg" class="footer-icon">
            <p>example@fylo.com</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="middle-footer-content col3">
          <p>About Us</p>
          <p>Jobs</p>
          <p>Press</p>
          <p>Blog</p>
        </div>

        <div class="end-footer-content col4">
          <p>Contact Us</p>
          <p>Terms</p>
          <p>Privacy</p>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-social-links col5">
          <img src="./images/icon-facebook.svg" class="social-icon">
          <img src="./images/icon-twitter.svg" class="social-icon">
          <img src="./images/icon-instagram.svg" class="social-icon">
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

The CSS:

```css
    .footer-content-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .col1 {
        grid-column: 1;
    }

    .col2 {
        grid-column: 2;
    }

    .col3 {
        grid-column: 3;
    }

    .col4 {
        grid-column: 4;
    }

    .col5 {
        grid-column: 5;
    }
```

[image: grid results]

Comment: There is issue with your `HTML` code.You have'nt written in corret order for desired output.[check this codepen](https://codepen.io/sayog/pen/ZEBaVZj) Is it what you want??

Comment: Yeah that's a really close fix for the desktop view, thanks. The location icon needed to be next to the paragraph text in the first column and I had to change it up a little for it to display correctly for my mobile view because the desktop view was a media query that created a grid layout. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Sayog the following code is the fixed version of my first post.

The HTML:

```
<footer>
      <div class="footer-content-container">
        <div class="col1">
          <img src="./images/logo.svg" class="footer-logo">
          <div class="footer-set">
            <img src="./images/icon-location.svg" class="footer-icon">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                Beatae doloremque voluptate perspiciatis cum eaque ad, repellendus 
                totam ducimus.
            </p>
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <div class="top-footer-content">
          <div class="footer-set col2">
            <img src="./images/icon-phone.svg" class="footer-icon">
            <p>+1-543-123-4567</p>
          </div>

          <div class="footer-set col2">
            <img src="./images/icon-email.svg" class="footer-icon">
            <p>example@fylo.com</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="middle-footer-content col3">
          <p>About Us</p>
          <p>Jobs</p>
          <p>Press</p>
          <p>Blog</p>
        </div>

        <div class="end-footer-content col4">
          <p>Contact Us</p>
          <p>Terms</p>
          <p>Privacy</p>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-social-links col5">
          <img src="./images/icon-facebook.svg" class="social-icon">
          <img src="./images/icon-twitter.svg" class="social-icon">
          <img src="./images/icon-instagram.svg" class="social-icon">
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

The CSS:

```
.footer-content-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 25% 20% 16% 16% 20%;
        grid-column-gap: 1em;
    }

    .footer-logo {
        width: 140px;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .footer-social-links {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .top-footer-content,
    .middle-footer-content,
    .end-footer-content,
    .footer-social-links {
        margin-top: 4em;
    }

    .col1 {
        grid-column: 1;
        max-width: 350px;
    }

    .col2 {
        grid-column: 2;
    }

    .col3 {
        grid-column: 3;
    }

    .col4 {
        grid-column: 4;
    }

    .col5 {
        grid-column: 5;
    }
```

[image: fixed-grid]